# Does the adjectives ordering exist in Ukrainian language?

Tags: граматика, прикметники

A lot of languages have some rules for multiply adjectives ordering, and English has them as well. For instance, the opinion of speaker becomes first, the size is second and the purpose of adjective is placed right before noun. Here is an example:

> They have a lovely old red post-box.

Does Ukrainian provide such rules or recommendations?

Comment: Related: Adjective ordering in English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike English, where there is a [well-defined order of adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5989/27), proven by numerous academic researches, Ukrainian lacks of such research.

One interesting work is described here (in Ukrainian): [Зіставлення порядку слідування ланцюжкових препозитивних атрибутів в англійській та українській мовах](http://studentam.net.ua/content/view/8281/97/) (Comparison of Order of Sequential Prepositional Adjectival Attributes in English and Ukrainian).

**Method**: the author has analyzed circa 1,000 examples in classic and modern Ukrainian literature and came up with the following conclusion.

This is my <s>lame</s> translation; original follows below.

> 1. Predeterminatives: один з (one of), обидва (both), усі (all/all of), половина (half) etc.
> 2. Determinatives:
>
>    - Possessive adjectives – мій (my), твій (your), її (her), свій (own) etc.;
>    - Demonstrative adjective – цей (this), той (that), такий (that of);
>    - Definitive¹ pronouns – усякий (each), інший (other), кожний (every)
>    - Indefinitive¹ pronouns – якийсь (some), деякий, певний (certain)
>    - Negation pronouns – ніякий (none of), нічий (nobody's).
> 3. Ordinals – перший (first), двадцятий (twentieth), сорок шостий (fourty-sixth), and also of relative order like наступний (next), попередній (previous), минулий (past), майбутній (future), останній (last)
> 4. Adjective of quantity – два (two), шістдесят (sixty)
>
>    - quantity qualifiers – декілька (several), багато (many), мало (few).
> 5. Axiological adjectives of common attitude – добрий (good), поганий (bad), чудовий (excellent), огидний (disgusting)
> 6. Axiological adjectives of special attitude:
>
>    1. Sensoric attitude:
>
>       - taste – приємний (pleasant), неприємний, смачний (tasty), несмачний, запашний, смердючий, гарячий (hot), сухий, вогкий
>       - psychological (intellectual and emotional): цікавий (interesting), нецікавий, захоплюючий, чудесний (wonderful), розумний (smart), дурний, радісний (happy), сумний (sad), жалкий (pity), небажаний (unnecessary)
>    2. Sublimated attitude
>
>       - aesthetic attitude: гарний (nice/beautiful), негарний, прекрасний, потворний (ugly)
>       - ethic attitude: моральний (moral), аморальний, добрий (good), злий, цнотливий (shy), розкутий
>       - teleological attitude: ефективний (effective), неефективний, доцільний (reasonable), недоцільний, вдалий (lucky), невдалий
> 7. Qualitative (non-axiological) adjectives, except those belonging to topics ## 8; 9; 10; 12 below: спритний, конвульсійний, лукавий
> 8. Qualitative adjectives of size: великий (big), малий (small), здоровенний (huge), крихітний (tiny), високий (tall), низький, довгий (long), короткий (short)
> 9. Qualitative adjectives of age: молодий (young), старий, дорослий (mature), двадцятирічний (twenty-years-old), давній (ancient)
> 10. Qualitative adjectives of form: круглий (round), квадратний, трикутний, товстий (thick), тонкий (thin), вузький (narrow), широкий (wide)
>
>     - Here go also adjectives like: босоногий (barefoot), голий (naked), зморшкуватий, лисий, веснянкуватий
> 11. Participles and participial adjectives: сказаний (said), прочитаний (read), тремтячий (trembling)
> 12. Qualitative adjectives of color, its intensity and relative qualities: білий (white), чорний, червоний, синій, жовтий, темний, світлий (bright), блідий, яскравий, блискучий (shiny), прозорий (opaque)
> 13. Adjective of of orientation: передній (front), задній, верхній (upper), нижній, лівий, правий, сусідній, боковий, горизонтальний, вертикальний
> 14. Adjectives of natural, national, or stylistic attribution: мамин (mother's), неньчин, батьків, Гнатів, Ольчин; дитячий (children's), жіночий, чоловічий, котячий, собачий, пташиний, гадючий; весняний (spring), літній, осінній, зимовий, ранковий, вечірній; український, англійський, парижський; класичний, античний і т.д.
> 15. Relative adjectives of material: залізний (iron), вовняний, дерев’яний (wooden), мідний, скляний
> 16. Adjectives of purpose, function, technical and social nature: дитяча (книга) (children's book), шкільні (посібники) (school books), хімічний (кабінет); армійський, десантний, авіаційний; дизельний, електричний, ламповий, лазерний; багатоклітинні, твердошкірий, кишковопорожнинні; суспільний, громадський, партійний, професійний, робочий, урядовий

**Notes**.
I haven't translated all examples; will do it in a while (sorry);
(¹) — this means that I'm not sure about the proper term for examples given

---

Original quote

> 1. Предетермінативи: один з, обидва, усі, половина і т.д.
> 2. Детермінативи:
>
>    - присвійні займенники – мій, твій, її, свій і т.д.;
>    - вказівні займенники – цей, той, такий;
>    - означальні займенники – усякий, інший, кожний і т.д.
>    - неозначені займенники – якийсь, деякий, певний і т.д.
>    - заперечні займенники – ніякий, нічий.
> 3. Порядкові числівники – перший, двадцятий, сорок шостий і т.д., а також прикметники типу наступний, попередній, минулий, майбутній, останній, і т.д.
> 4. Кількісні числівники – два, шістдесят, сорок шостий і т.д.; квантифікатори кількості – декілька, багато, мало.
> 5. Аксіологічні прикметники загальної оцінки – добрий, поганий, чудовий, огидний і т.д.
> 6. Аксіологічні прикметники конкретної оцінки.
>
>    1. Сенсорної оцінки:
>
>       - сенсорно-смакові – приємний, неприємний, смачний, несмачний, запашний, смердючий, гарячий, сухий, вогкий і т.д.
>       - психологічні оцінки (інтелектуальні і емоціональні): цікавий, нецікавий, захоплюючий, чудесний, розумний, дурний, радісний, сумний, жалкий, небажаний і т.д.
>    2. Сублімовані оцінки
>
>       - естетичні оцінки: гарний, негарний, прекрасний, потворний і т.д.
>       - етичні оцінки: моральний, аморальний, добрий, злий, цнотливий, розкутий і т.д.
>       - телеологічні оцінки: ефективний, неефективний, доцільний, недоцільний, вдалий, невдалий і т.д.
> 7. Якісні (не аксіологічні) прикметники, крім приналежних до позицій 8; 9; 10; 12: спритний, конвульсійний, лукавий і т.д.
> 8. Якісні прикметники, що означають розмір: великий, малий, здоровенний, крихітний, високий, низький, довгий, короткий і т.д.
> 9. Якісні прикметники, що означають вік: молодий, старий, дорослий, двадцятирічний, давній і т.д.
> 10. Якісні прикметники, що означають форму: круглий, квадратний, трикутний, товстий, тонкий, вузький, шорокий і т.д. Сюди ж належать прикметники типу: босоногий, голий, зморшкуватий, лисий, веснянкуватий і ін.
> 11. Дієприкметники та віддієприкметникові прикметники: сказаний, прочитаний, тремтячий і т.д.
> 12. Якісні прикметники, що означають колір, його інтенсивність та інші супроводжуючі ознаки: білий, чорний, червоний, синій, жовтий, темний, світлий, блідий, яскравий, блискучий, прозорий і т.д.
> 13. Прикметники, що означають розташування в просторі: передній, задній, верхній, нижній, лівий, правий, сусідній, боковий, горизонтальний, вертикальний і т.д.
> 14. Прикметники зі значенням присвійності, притаманності, національної, стильової та іншої належності: мамин, неньчин, батьків, Гнатів, Ольчин; дитячий, жіночий, чоловічий, котячий, собачий, пташиний, гадючий; весняний, літній, осінній, зимовий, ранковий, вечірній; український, англійський, парижський; класичний, античний і т.д.
> 15. Відносні прикметники, що означають матеріал: залізний, вовняний, дерев’яний, мідний, скляний і т.д.
> 16. Прикметники, що означають призначення, функційні, технічні, класифікаційні та соціальні різновиди: дитяча (книга), шкільні (посібники), хімічний (кабінет); армійський, десантний, авіаційний; дизельний, електричний, ламповий, лазерний; багатоклітинні, твердошкірий, кишковопорожнинні; суспільний, громадський, партійний, професійний, робочий, урядовий і т.д.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, dude, for such detailed answer and huge translating work.

Comment: This researcher is right. Never heard of this issue before but as a native-speaker I sense when described order gets altered, although it's not forbidden, because it may sound a bit unnatural.

Answer (score 4):

**UPD.** Actually, you are free to use adjectives in any order. It depends on what are you going to put the accent on. For your example with the lovely old red post-box you may say "чудова/мила стара червона поштова скриня", "червона мила стара скриня" or even "чудова червона поштова мила скриня". It would sound somewhat weird.

Basically, you should use the order as in yours example, but it is not the mistake to shuffle adjectives according to your language tastes

---

**Old answer:** In the Ukrainian language you are not stuck with a defined order of words. It is up to you how to use it. But in the official documents and letters you ought to use the direct order (it is similar with English). You can read more on Pidruchiki website [here](http://pidruchniki.com/1776121447619/dokumentoznavstvo/poryadok_sliv_rechenni) about the sentence ordering.

Up to your questions, such words as "to my mind", "in my opinion" etc. can be in any part of the sentence as well. Each of them is so-called parenthesis, you must separate them by comas. [Further reading](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/sintaksis_i_punktuacija/vstavni_slova_i_rechennja/7-1-0-206)

So, to summarize, you are allowed to say "**In my opinion**, it was cold yesterday" like following:

"**На мою думку**, вчора було холодно"

"Вчора, **на мою думку**, було холодно"

"Вчора було холодно, **на мою думку**"

Well, the last one is used rarely. The first and the second are almost equal in usage.