# Позиція прикметників

Tags: прикметники

Які є унормування чи ствердження поважних мовознавців щодо розташування прикметників: поперед чи після іменника?

Я знаю лише те, що зазвичай прикметики стоять перед іменником.

---

Про порядок прикметників вже [було.](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/134/)

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, [цей допис](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2213/1009) відповідає на запитання.

Коротко кажучи, у більшості мов словʼянської групи, прикметник ставиться перед іменником. Єдиний значний виняток — **якщо призначення прикметника полягає у відзначенні одного обʼєкта серед групи інших, подібних йому, обʼєктів**
(англ: *If the purpose of adjective is to classify the denoted entity which belongs to a certain category or type*).

Іншим історичним прикладом є релігійні тексти, де постфіксний прикметник використовується досить широко і відзначає сакральний сенс. Цікава паралель: у санскриті саме так і відбувається, і деякі мови Південно-Східної Азії (наприклад, тайська і лаоська) успадкували постфіксний прикметник як основну граматичну форму.